# Input pages of nonsense using for testing purposes

Tags: packages

### Problem

I remembered seeing this multiple times on this site, one can specify how many pages of nonsense to input to check that some global page settings (margins, page numbers etc) are correct. But I do not remember the name of this package and I could not find it by Google.

More generally, if I want to know a package for some specific purpose, which site could I use so that no such questions would be asked here.

Comment: If you just want to create, say, 10 pages, you could simply do `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,10}
{~\clearpage}
\end{document}`. Strictly speaking `pgffor` is not needed for that, you could use `\loop` instead. `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\loop
~\clearpage
\ifnum\thepage<10\repeat
\end{document}`

Comment: You should also have a look at package `blindtext`. It provides more than just lines and lines of text, it provides dummy documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know Latin? No? Then this produces 10 pages of nonsense:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document} 
\loop \lipsum[\thepage]\clearpage \ifnum\thepage<10\repeat 
\end{document}
```

Of course, you can replace 10 by other numbers, I checked that 100 works.

Comment: This is exactly I am looking for, thank you!